# MVC 4 application in .net framework 3.5 SP1

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

We have developed an application using ASP.NET MVC 4. This app needs to be installed in 2500 stores which have .net 3.5 SP1 but Application requires at least .NET 4.0.

We cannot upgrade all stores to .net 4.0 and although being web app it has to be placed individually at each store (cannot be placed at centralized server - Its requirement).

I have VS 2013 in machine and as per my knowledge MVC 2 app cannot be developed in VS 2013.

Is there any way to run mvc 4 app on 3.5 SP1 framework?
What are my options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my knowledge, No we cannot run MVC 4 on 3.5 SP1 Framework.

This are the requirements for MVC 4:

**Supported operating systems**: Windows 7, Windows Server 2003 R2 (32-Bit x86), Windows Server 2003 R2 x64 editions, Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 2, Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Vista Service Pack 2, Windows XP Service Pack 3

PowerShell 2.0, .NET 4, ASP.NET 4, and Visual Studio 2010 SP1 or Visual Web Developer 2010 SP1 are required to use this feature.